# Mobile Safari not showing CSS transform rotateX and rotateY only rotateZ

Tags: ios, css, iphone, device-orientation, webkit-transform

This is weird. I'm playing with device orientation but can't seem to get rotateX and rotateY to work in Safari (iOS 8.0.2).

But! if I save it to my home screen with apple-web-app-capable meta tag it works fine.

This is my script:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", handleOrientation, true);

function handleOrientation(e) {
  var alpha    = e.alpha;
  var beta     = e.beta;
  var gamma    = e.gamma;
  $('#z').val(Math.round(alpha)); // Z
  $('#x').val(Math.round(beta)); //  X
  $('#y').val(Math.round(gamma)); // Y
  document.getElementById("box").style.webkitTransform="rotateZ("+Math.round(-alpha)+"deg) rotateX("+Math.round(beta)+"deg) rotateY("+Math.round(-gamma)+"deg)"; 
}
});
```

you can see it here live (on your iPhone): http://kohlin.net/matte/orientation.html
Then try saving it to your home screen.

Any clues? A bug?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a bug in ios Safari browser.
To fix this, surround the box div with another  tag.  Then move the css:

```
-webkit-perspective: 500px;
```

to the containing div.  This should make the rotating box visible.